# How to add errors before updating attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, delayed-job

I'm trying to handle the situation where the user has entered info incorrectly, so I have a path that follows roughly:

```
class Thing < AR
  before_validation :byebug_hook
  def byebug_hook
    byebug
  end
end

thing = Thing.find x
thing.errors.add(:foo, "bad foo")
# Check byebug here, and errors added
if thing.update_attributes(params)
  DelayedJobThatDoesntLikeFoo.perform
else
  flash.now.errors = #...
end

byebug for byebug_hook> errors.messages #=> {}
```

Originally I thought that maybe the model was running its own validations and overwriting the ones I added, but as you can see even when I add the before hook the errors are missing, and I'm not sure what's causing it

ACTUAL SOLUTION
So, @SteveTurczyn was right that the errors needed to happen in a certain place, in this case a service object called in my controller

The change I made was

```
class Thing < AR
validate :includes_builder_added_errors
    def builder_added_errors
      @builder_added_errors ||= Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
    end

  def includes_builder_added_errors
    builder_added_errors.each {|k, v| errors.set(k, v) }
  end
end

and in the builder object
thing = Thing.find x
# to my thinking this mirrors the `errors.add` syntax better
thing.builder_added_errors[:foo].push("bad foo") if unshown_code_does_stuff?
if thing.update_attributes(params)
  DelayedJobThatDoesntLikeFoo.perform
else
  flash.now.errors = #...
end
```

Comment: I think in your attempt to make your code snippet concise you've made it difficult to follow. In either case I think you'll find the answer to your questions [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_attributes` will validate the model... this includes clearing all existing errors and then running any before_validation callbacks.  Which is why there are never any errors at the pont of `before_validation`

If you want to add an error condition to the "normal" validation errors you would be better served to do it as a custom validation method in the model.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :add_foo_error

  def add_foo_error
    errors.add(:foo, "bad foo")
  end
end
```

If you want some validations to occur only in certain controllers or conditions, you can do that by setting an `attr_accessor` value on the model, and setting a value before you run validations directly (:valid?) or indirectly (:update, :save).

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :check_foo
  validate :add_foo_error

  def add_foo_error
    errors.add(:foo, "bad foo") if check_foo
  end
end
```

In the controller...

```
thing = Thing.find x
thing.check_foo = true
if thing.update_attributes(params)
  DelayedJobThatDoesntLikeFoo.perform
else
  flash.now.errors = #...
end
```